# Ported Software Version Numbering

Tags: version-numbering

If I have a piece of software for Mac that I wrote that is past it's 1.0.0 release (for example, its at version 1.3 currently) and I want to create a Windows version of my app now to be released with version 1.4, would it be more suitable to release the Windows version at 1.0.0 or 1.4 to be consistent with my Mac version?

Thanks.

Comment: You would certainly want them to be consistent between OSes, though version numbering ultimately means nothing to those not working on the development -- it is only used by the development team to track changes, and **how** you track those 'versions' is up to you :)

Comment: I've been using Semantic Versioning 2.0.0.  I suppose I'd prefer for the versions to be aligned.